# How to ues npm.commands.test function

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, npm

I would like to create a function that can return the result by npm test.

(by call this function `npm.commands.test(packages, callback)` https://docs.npmjs.com/api/test)

I tried to use that like this:

```
var npm = require("npm");
npm.load('', function(err, npm) {
  npm.commands.test('package.json', function(data) {
  });
});
```

It could run such as command `npm test`, but I don't know how to get the result? and what is the callback function like?

Answer (score 1):

`npm.commands.test` executes the test command defined in the package.json file of the current project. Additionally, `npm.commands.test` redirects the first parameter to the test command.

### Example

package.json:

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "test": "mocha"
    }
    ...
}
```

code:

```
var npm = require('npm');
...
npm.commands.test('myTestDirectory', function(err){
    // if one of more tests failed, err will be set to the string:
    // 'Test failed.  See above for more details.'
    // Else, err will be undefined.
});
```

calls:

```
/path/to/project/root> mocha "myTestDirectory"
```

In some situations, especially if you want to execute tests of another project or package, it probably makes more sense to use the `child_process` module to spawn a new process of `npm test` and access the output over the process' stderr and stdout streams or call the test runner of the particular project directly.